Return early in loop over discriminated union match / switch
I am writing an API that has endpoints to both update a single item and multiple items. In the endpoint to update multiple items, I want to reuse the function to update a single item by simply looping over all items to update. The single update function currently has three possible return values (implemented with a discriminated union by using OneOf):

The updated item
An OneOf.NotFound-instance in case the update didn't previously exist
An OneOf.Error-instance in case there was some other issue (e.g. a validation error)

In the bulk update endpoint, I would like to return early in case an item update resulted in an error. I tried using the Match and Switch methods provided by OneOf, but I couldn't figure out how to achieve the behavior I described. Here is my current version of the endpoint code:
routes.MapPut(RouteBases.ShoppingList, async (IEnumerable<ShoppingListItem> itemsToUpdate, MariaDbContext dbContext) =>
{
    var storedItems = new List<ShoppingListItem>();
    var failedItems = new List<ShoppingListItem>();
    var state = (storedItems, failedItems);
    foreach (var item in itemsToUpdate)
    {
        var updateResult = await UpdateItem(item, dbContext);
        state = updateResult.Match<(IEnumerable<ShoppingListItem>, IEnumerable<ShoppingListItem>)>(
            storedItem => (storedItems.Append(storedItem), failedItems),
            notFound => (storedItems, failedItems.Append(item)),
            error => { return Results.BadRequest(); }
            );
    }

    await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

    return Results.Ok(new BulkUpdateResult(storedItems, failedItems));
});

Obviously, the error-case in my Match can't compile, because its return type cannot be converted to the expected type, but it should demonstrate the wanted behavior. How can I do that correctly, or is my approach fundamentally flawed?
P.S.: While writing this, I wondered whether it's right to return early in case there is an error only. This would be a bit inconsistent with the case that an item couldn't be found. I should probably either change the code to not return early and to aggregate the errors as well, or to also return early in case of a NotFound update result. For this API, I might choose to return the aggregated values as well. Still, I would be very much interested in knowing how to solve this problem, as in other, similar cases it might be necessary to return early (e.g. "costly" calls in the loop).

"how to solve this problem, as in other, similar cases it might be necessary to return early (e.g. "costly" calls in the loop)" - did it occur to you that in different cases, different solutions might apply? So, what is the question? A solution to the specific use case you are having here or a one-fits-all solution for all "similar" use-cases or specific solutions for a bunch of specific, distinct but similar use-cases ?

@Fildor I'm sorry if my P.S. didn't express clearly enough that I am aware that there are different solutions already that I can think of. I tried to describe that a trivial solution would be to aggregate the errors as well. I also tried to describe that I am still interested in how one could return early in a case similar to the show code, as one might come across a case in the future where e.g. any unnecessary call to the Update function should be avoided. I also think that showing multiple options with their pros and cons is essential to making an informed decision.

I am not sure how Match method looks like, but to return early you have to manually iterate with the loop. I don't see other option. Or maybe changing implementation of Match if you can.

@MichałTurczyn Match is a method provided by the OneOf package to make sure that you handle all cases of a discriminated union. So no, changing it is not an option.

The answer is traverse. It's always traverse.
If you're interested in functional programming, look up traversals. They generally address this kind of problem. (FWIW, I have an article about traversals queued up, but it'll be some weeks yet before I publish it.)
That said, there are so many things going on in the code shown in the OP that it's hardly functional:

The presence of async and await strongly suggests IO.
The implementation mutates state.
The implementation uses foreach instead of recursion or a higher-order function like Select or Aggregate. (But, as indicated, you'll most likely need some kind of traversal. For Task-based collections, this could be Task.WhenAll or Task.WhenAny, but IIRC, none of those are short-circuiting.)

Unless you want to entirely rewrite the entire implementation to split pure functions from impure actions, I suggest you instead do something like this:
var storedItems = new List<ShoppingListItem>();
var failedItems = new List<ShoppingListItem>();
var state = (storedItems, failedItems, hasError: false);
foreach (var item in itemsToUpdate)
{
    var updateResult = await UpdateItem(item, dbContext);
    state = updateResult.Match<(List<ShoppingListItem>, List<ShoppingListItem>, bool)>(
        storedItem => { storedItems.Add(storedItem); return state;  },
        notFound => { failedItems.Add(notFound); return state; },
        error => { state.hasError = true; return state; }
        );
    if (state.hasError)
        return Results.BadRequest();
}

await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

return Results.Ok(new BulkUpdateResult(storedItems, failedItems));

This isn't functional at all, but neither was the code in the OP, and it's a fairly simple change that you can make.
If you want to collect the errors too, make a collection for them instead of the Boolean flag, and add the errors in the foreach loop.

This is pretty similar to the solution that I found. I was trying to write more functional approach, but didn't realize how far I still have to go. To me, it would be very interesting to see how I should implement this as purely functional as possible. With your great hints, I'll try myself, but feel free to show a more functional solution as well or give me more pointers to what to look out for!

@causaprima Refactoring to a more functional style is a bigger task, but not without interest in this case. It's too big for an answer here, IMO, but I'll write a couple of blog posts in the coming weeks. I'll post an update here when I publish the first.

@causaprima I've now written the article and queued it up, but it turned out that I'll need to cover some other stuff first. As Carl Sagan said, "If you wish to make an apple pie from scratch, you must first invent the universe." I'll keep you posted.

@causaprima As promised, here's an article that addresses the first of the two alternatives: https://blog.ploeh.dk/2024/11/18/collecting-and-handling-result-values

@causaprima And here's the second article that describes the other alternative: https://blog.ploeh.dk/2024/12/02/short-circuiting-an-asynchronous-traversal

After some more reflection, I found a solution that solves the problem:
routes.MapPut($"{RouteBases.ShoppingList}", async (IEnumerable<ShoppingListItem> itemsToUpdate, MariaDbContext dbContext) =>
{
    IEnumerable<ShoppingListItem> storedItems = new List<ShoppingListItem>();
    IEnumerable<ShoppingListItem> failedItems = new List<ShoppingListItem>();
    var hadError = false;
    foreach (var item in itemsToUpdate)
    {
        var updateResult = await UpdateItem(item, dbContext);
        (storedItems, failedItems, hadError) = updateResult.Match<(IEnumerable<ShoppingListItem> storedItems, IEnumerable<ShoppingListItem> failedItems, bool hadError)>(
            storedItem => (storedItems.Append(storedItem), failedItems, hadError),
            notFound => (storedItems, failedItems.Append(item), hadError),
            error => (storedItems, failedItems, true)
            );
        if (hadError) return Results.BadRequest();
    }

    await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

    return Results.Ok(new BulkUpdateResult(storedItems, failedItems));
});

I was close before with using a state, but didn't realize that the error could also be a state. Also note that (as my P.S. suggested) one could easily change this code to aggregate the errors as well by using some collection instead of a simple boolean (hadError).
As there might be alternatives to what I came up with, please don't hesitate to share other solutions, so we can evaluate the pros and cons of each approach.
